# How to debug HTML/CSS for iPhone/iPad performance?

Tags: html, ios, css

I am creating a page that should work fine on both desktop and mobile.

On desktop I can use Chrome Developer Tool or Firebug to debug/adjust every details quite easily. But how do I make it perfect on mobile?

Is there anyway I can turn my Chrome to a iPhone-sized view?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Chrome's debug tools let you set the constraints of the page you're viewing.

- F12 / right-click [Inspect Element]
- Click the gear icon (bottom right)
- Check `[ ]` Enable under Overrides
- Set your User Agent, Device Metrics, Geolocation and Device Orientation

Comment: Oh, thanks. I just noticed that this is already available in `32.0.1700.76 (Official Build 244343)`!

Comment: It's been there since 27 I believe ;)

Answer (score 0):

Well, I found this feature in Chrome Canary version:

https://www.google.com/intl/en/chrome/browser/canary.html

Just hit <kbd>ESC</kbd> in developer tool view and it has a very amazing tool for help. Currently the combobox might have some bug but you can use <kbd>up</kbd> / <kbd>down</kbd> keys to select devices.